# Recorrer Array de Objects con Jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo un array de objects de colores y es el siguiente:
 [Color [id=1, codigoOColor=Rojo], Color [id=2, codigoOColor=Verde]] 
Y necesito recorrer dicho array de Colores mediante la libreria jquery y pintarlo en un option de un select, he probado este codigo pero da el siguiente fallo:

```
function Color(id, codigoOColor) { 
this.id = id, 
this.codigoOColor = codigoOColor 
}

      function mostrarColores(){
            $.each(colores, function(color){

            let html = `<option>${color.id}</option>`;

            $("#ejemploColor").append(html);
        }); 
    }

    mostrarColores();
```

Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [Color [id=1, codigoOColor=Rojo], Color [id=2, codigoOColor=Verde]]

Answer (score 2):

Te faltaría añadir a la función **[`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** de JQuery, el índice como parámetro.

Tal y como dice la documentación:

> En el caso de un array, al callback se le pasa un índice y su correspondiente valor cada vez.

```js
var color1 = {
  id: 1,
  codigoOColor: "Rojo"
}

var color2 = {
  id: 2,
  codigoOColor: "Verde"
}

var arrayObjetos = [color1, color2];

function mostrarColores(){
    $.each(arrayObjetos, function(indice, color){
      let html = "<option>" + color.id + "</option>";
      $("#ejemploColor").append(html);
    }); 
}

mostrarColores();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ejemploColor"></select>
```

Para tu caso concreto también podrías acceder al objeto sin pasarle ningún parámetro a la función `.each()` mediante la palabra reservada `this`.

```js
var color1 = {
  id: 1,
  codigoOColor: "Rojo"
}

var color2 = {
  id: 2,
  codigoOColor: "Verde"
}

var arrayObjetos = [color1, color2];

function mostrarColores(){
    $.each(arrayObjetos, function(){
      let html = "<option>" + this.id + "</option>";
      $("#ejemploColor").append(html);
    }); 
}

mostrarColores();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ejemploColor"></select>
```

Pero tal y como indica la documentación:

> El valor también puede ser obtenido a través the la palabra clave `this`, pero Javascript siempre envolverá el valor de `this` como un objeto incluso si es un simple string o un valor numérico.